# mapDispatchToProps dispatch action not working to update State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In my **index.js** the `addCoin` action is working.

```
import { addCoin } from './reducer/portfolio/actions'

const element = document.getElementById('coinhover');

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
));

store.dispatch(addCoin('bitcoin'));
```

When `store.dispatch` is called I can see the updated state here.
[image]

However I do not want to call dispatch actions from my index.js, but from within my components.

---

#### My SearchCoin component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as R from 'ramda'
import * as api from '../../services/api'
import { addToPortfolio, findCoins } from '../../services/coinFactory'
import { addCoin } from '../../reducer/portfolio/actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    selectCoin(coin) {
        return () => {
            dispatch(addCoin(coin))
        }
    }
});

class SearchCoin extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            searched: []
        };
        // console.log('props', props);
        this.close = this.close.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.coinInput.focus(); 
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.clickCoin = this.clickCoin.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange() {
        const text = document.getElementById('coin-search').value;
        const search = (text)  => this.setState({ searched: findCoins(text) });
        const clearSearch = () => this.setState({ searched: [] });
        text.length > 1 ? search(text) : clearSearch();
    }

    clickCoin(coin) {
        console.log('clickCoin', coin);
        // api.getCoin(coin.id).then((res) => {
        //  const apiCoin = R.head(res.data);
        //  addToPortfolio(apiCoin);
        // });
        this.props.selectCoin(coin);
        this.props.closeSearch();
    }

    close() {
        this.props.closeSearch();
    }

    render() {
        const searched = this.state.searched.map((coin) => {
            return (
                <li key={ coin.id } onClick={ ()=> this.clickCoin(coin) }>
                    <div className="coin-logo">
                        <img src={ coin.logo }/>
                    </div>
                    <span>{ coin.name }</span>
                </li>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div id="search-coin-component">
                <input type="text"
                       id="coin-search"
                       className="coin-search-input fl"
                       placeholder="Search"
                       onChange={ ()=> this.handleChange() }
                       ref={ (input) => { this.coinInput = input; } } />
                <div className="icon-cancel-outline fl" onClick={ this.close }></div>
                <div className="coin-select">
                    <ul>
                        { searched }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchCoin)
```

This is the onClick:

`<li key={ coin.id } onClick={ ()=> this.clickCoin(coin) }>`

At the bottom of the file I am using connect to add `mapDispatchToProps`

`export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchCoin)`

Here is the class method `clickCoin` which calls `this.props.selectCoin`

```
clickCoin(coin) {
    console.log('clickCoin', coin);
    this.props.selectCoin(coin);
    this.props.closeSearch();
}
```

Finally `selectCoin`

```
import { addCoin } from '../../reducer/portfolio/actions'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    selectCoin(coin) {
        return () => {
            dispatch(addCoin(coin))
        }
    }
});
```

However when I click the button it seems like the dispatch is not fired as nothing happens to the redux state.[image]

```
import * as R from 'ramda'
import * as api from '../../services/api'
import { addToPortfolio } from '../../services/coinFactory'

export const ADD_COIN = 'ADD_COIN'

export function addCoin(coin) {
    console.log('addCoin', coin);
    return dispatch =>
        api.getCoin(coin)
            .then((res) => addToPortfolio(R.head(res.data)))
            .then((portfolio) => dispatch(add(portfolio)));
}

// action creator
export function add(portfolio) {
    return {
        type: ADD_COIN,
        portfolio
    }
}
```

#### The reducer

```
import { ADD_COIN } from './actions'

const initialState = [];

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_COIN:
            return action.portfolio;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

#### the reducer/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import portfolio from './portfolio'

export default combineReducers({
    portfolio
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `bindActionCreators` from `redux`? `selectCoin: bindActionCreators(addCoin, dispatch)` inside the object returned from `mapDispatchToProps`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are wrapping your function with an extra function.

Change:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  selectCoin(coin) {
    return () => { <--- returning extra function
      dispatch(addCoin(coin))
    }
  }
})
```

to:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  selectCoin(coin) { dispatch(addCoin(coin)) }
})
```

Comment: Ah bam that was it! Thanks :D

Answer (score 6):

Apart from azium answer, you can use actions like this. It saves you some writing,

```
export default connect(null, {addCoin})(SearchCoin)
```

and you can use it like this,

```
clickCoin(coin) {
    console.log('clickCoin', coin);
    this.props.addCoin(coin);
    this.props.closeSearch();
}
```

Comment: Nice! Great tip and +1!

Comment: Does this bind the action creator to dispatch?